# PHP Script Issues - Contact Form

Tags: php, html

I am writing a contact form for a website and am having trouble getting it to send the fields of my form on the actual e-mail.

The e-mails are sent and received successfully though.

Here is my HTML

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" style="font-size:12px;">
            <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">

            <p>Telephone</p><input type="text" name="phone" size="30" />

            <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">

            <p>Message</p><textarea name="comments" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

            <p>Best time to Contact You</p><input type="text" size="15" name="time" />

            <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>
```

and my PHP

```
    <?php
$to = "myemailaddress";
$subject = "New Website Enquiry";
$message = "You have recieved a new enquiry";
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['comments, phone, time'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;


$url = 'index.html';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['comments, phone, time'];` is a field that in $_POST that has the name `'comments, phone, time'` - it's not the same as catting those three fields together.

Comment: You have 2 variable with message also 2nd one is unacceptable

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn basic PHP syntax.

```
$message = $_POST['comments, phone, time'];
```

is outright wrong. You cannot specify multiply array keys in a comma-separated list like that, let along within a STRING. The code should be more like:

```
$message = $_POST['comments'] . $_POST['phone'] . $_POST['time'];
```

Note that what you have is **NOT** a php-level syntax error. You're using a perfectly acceptable array key, which simply happens to not exist.

Comment: How embaressing, the code i copied in the question was one that was copied off a tut site, I do know basic PHP but my mind went blank, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found an syntax error in your code:

Change

`$message = $_POST['comments, phone, time'];`

to

`$message = $_POST['comments'] . . $_POST['phone'] . $_POST['time'];`

What else do you have a problem with?

Comment: Nothing at all! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$to = "myemailaddress"; 
$subject = "New Website Enquiry"; 
$message = "You have recieved a new enquiry"; 
$from = $_POST['email']; 
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$headers = "From:" . $from; 
$url = 'index.html'; 
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0;URL='.$url.'">'; mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 

?>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of tweaking the formatting a touch; if you use the `{}` button in the editor, it formats text as code for you.

Comment: Thanks @andrewsi actually I answered the question via my Samsung note it didn't allow me to format the answer. Stackooverflow should do something so that the website can be used via mobile device too

Comment: I suspect it's been mentioned there before, but http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ would be the place to ask for that.

Comment: @Adam did you get it correct

Comment: Yes got that working, although does anybody know how to make a string of text appear before the output on an email

Comment: for example

BEST TIME TO BE CONTACTED (TEXT) - then . $_POST['time'];

Comment: That's correct "some text". $_POST['time']

Comment: @Adam please credit the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: It says unexpected t string in quotes?

Comment: @Adam Check now updated my code